# PHP - simplexml_load_file() - I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, xml, ssh

Im trying to display a xml file from a ssh server. My connection is working, i can display the file but only with a warning. I searched in internet for more explications but i found nothing that's why im here today. If you have some ideas, dont be shy :)

Thanks in advance.

The code :

```
 $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'cat //Talend//PEC_DF6//FluxSortantAdmissionPEC//ARCHIVES//XML//wzadyyyy.0001057582.ap.xml');
 stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
 $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
 $xqc = simplexml_load_file($output);  
 echo "<pre>$xqc</pre>";die();
```

---

The error :

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : 
failed to load external entity 
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<BL_RA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Resultats_Admission_2.04.xsd"> 
<ResultatAdmission CodeEtatSuiviDepot="ECPEC" DateEtatSuiviDepot="22-01- 
2019" DateDepot="21-01-2019" HeureDepot="20:00" CodeSiteDepot="932930"> 
<Identification NumeroBIP="0000809106"> <IdentificationDepot 
NumDepot="MA570430"/> <Publication IDPCD="1482270" NoParution="331" 
TypeParution="SUP1"/> </Identification> </ResultatAdmission> </BL_RA> " 
in D:\www\SAGAPEC\application\modules\supervision\controllers\AdminController.php on line 386
```

---

The original XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<BL_RA xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Resultats_Admission_2.04.xsd" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

 -<ResultatAdmission CodeSiteDepot="932930" HeureDepot="20:00" 
   DateDepot="21-01-2019" DateEtatSuiviDepot="22-01-2019" 
   CodeEtatSuiviDepot="ECPEC">


      -<Identification NumeroBIP="0000809106">

            <IdentificationDepot NumDepot="MA570430"/>

               <Publication TypeParution="SUP1" NoParution="331" 
               IDPCD="1482270"/>

        </Identification>

     </ResultatAdmission>

 </BL_RA>
```

Comment: yes of course, i will do it immediatly. @NigelRen

Comment: Appologies for not noticing this before, but `simplexml_load_file` should be passed a file name to load `simplexml_load_string()` is the function I think you want.

Comment: Also to get the output as XML, replace the last line with `echo "<pre>".$xqc->asXML()."</pre>";`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help, i can display now the all the attributes and values from the XML file. Can you give some tracks for display the XML attributes and values like an original XML. `echo "<pre>".$xqc->asXML()."</pre>";` gives me nothing :/

Comment: If this is being echoed to a browser page, try viewing the source to check what it there.

Comment: Finally it's ok, i used the function htmlsecialchars(); and it's working ! thanks for all !